# Unable to parse a json data in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, nsdictionary

I have a API response as given below:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "schedule_data": {
        "2020_08_16_1597485600": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-16",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "06:00",
            "shift_end": "13:00",
            "schedule_id": 112
        },
        "2020_08_16": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-16",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_17_1597485600": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-17",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "06:00",
            "shift_end": "22:00",
            "schedule_id": 113
        },
        "2020_08_17": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-17",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_18": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-18",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_19": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-19",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_20": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-20",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_21": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-21",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_22": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-22",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_23": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-23",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_24": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-24",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_25": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-25",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_26": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-26",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_27": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-27",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_28": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-28",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_29": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-29",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_30": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-30",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        },
        "2020_08_31": {
            "schedule_date": "2020-08-31",
            "nanny_id": 2,
            "shift_start": "",
            "shift_end": "",
            "schedule_id": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I have the data model for this API response and it is as follows:

```
import Foundation

struct Welcome: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let scheduleData: [String: ScheduleDatum]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case scheduleData = "schedule_data"
    }
}

// MARK: - ScheduleDatum
struct ScheduleDatum: Codable {
    let scheduleDate: String?
    let nannyID: Int?
    let shiftStart: String?
    let shiftEnd: String?
    let scheduleID: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case scheduleDate = "schedule_date"
        case nannyID = "nanny_id"
        case shiftStart = "shift_start"
        case shiftEnd = "shift_end"
        case scheduleID = "schedule_id"
    }
}
```

I want the schedule_date values for the data where the schedule_id is not zero.This schedule_data is an array of dictionary.The json parsing is done this way in the ios swift code.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      
      do {
          
          let user = try decoder.decode(ScheduleListModel.self, from: response.data!)
          self.listdata = user
       

       
        if (self.listdata?.scheduleData.count)! > 0
       {

       }
       else
       {
        self.showAlert(message: "No schedule available")
       }
       
         } catch {
             debugPrint(error)
      }
```

How to fetch the values inside the dictionary of this array?

Comment: What is `ScheduleListModel`? You should decode `Welcome`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to be improved here. First, the model properties don't have to be optional if the keys never become `nil`. Secondly, the coding keys are not required as the same can be achieved by `convertFromSnakeCase`.

Model:

```
let data = Data(string.utf8)

struct Welcome: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let scheduleData: [String: ScheduleDatum]
}

struct ScheduleDatum: Codable {
    let scheduleDate: String
    let nannyId: Int
    let shiftStart: String
    let shiftEnd: String
    let scheduleId: Int
}
```

Decoding needs to be done to the model `Welcome`. Also, loop through the data to get the `scheduleDates`. Here's how:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

    let user = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: response.data)
    var scheduleDates = [String]()

    for schedule in user.scheduleData {
        if schedule.value.scheduleId != 0 {
            scheduleDates.append(schedule.value.scheduleDate)
        }
    }
    print(scheduleDates)
} catch {
    debugPrint(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter dictionary based on its values and fetch the dates. You should use `Welcome` model to parse the JSON and do the filtering.

Here is the code :

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder.init()

let welcomeModel = try! decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: response.data)

welcomeModel.scheduleData.enumerated().forEach {
    if $1.value.scheduleID != 0 || $1.value.scheduleID != nil {
        print($1.value.scheduleDate ?? "Date is nil")
    } 
}
```